# unable to find a medium with a live file system in ubuntu 14.04 using wubi Windows installer

Tags: 14.04

hi i am installing ubuntu 14.04 or any version from wubi  (Windows Installer) but after restarting the windows its throws me error that its unable to find a medium  with a live system . i also tried with install to create a bootable pen drive but still it didnt work out . i also tried to change the bios to sata from achi but still it showing me the same error.
i use ubuntu before but never faced this problem before but now this problem coming why ??

I m using hp540 laptop with windows7 32 bit

help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to just link to a bug report, but there were many suggested fixes for your issue there and it's worth it to try each of them out:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1241589

For me, I was able to get a 14.04 live USB to boot on my Lenovo Y580 without removing any hardware, using AHCI mode for Sata and no legacy mode enabled anywhere in the BIOS by using the `live-media` trick mentioned in [comment 55](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1241589/comments/55) in combination with removing and re-inserting my USB drive soon after boot. Note that the symptoms I was seeing were a bit different; specifically in the initramfs prompt, when I ran `blkid` I didn't see the USB device (eg my USB was on `/dev/sdc` and all I saw were `/dev/sda*` and `/dev/sdb*`). Thus I edited the boot command (as described in comment 55) to add `live-media=/dev/sdc1` and removed the `quite splash`. After the boot output paused for a bit, I removed then re-inserted my USB and it worked fine from there.